# Can multiple if statements be associated with a single else clause without using else-if?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a validation method in which I have to check conditions one by one and then throw error messages accordingly.

To achieve this, I am using multiple if statements, and if all the conditions are false, I should execute a task.

Here's my code:

```
if(s1.equals("") || s2.equals("") || s3.equals("") || s4.equals("") || s5.equals("") || s6.equals(""))      
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter all Details first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
if(!s5.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+"))     
    e5.setError("Username cannot contain special characters");      
if(s5.length()<6)
    e5.setError("Username must be a minimum of 6 characters.");
if(!(s3.contains("@")&& s3.contains(".")))
    e3.setError("Enter a valid Email Id");      
if(!s6.equals(s7))
    e7.setError("Passwords dont match");
if(s2.length()!=10)     
    e2.setError("Please enter a valid 10 digit number");        
else
{
    Validate v2=new Validate();
    v2.store_values(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s8);
    v2.execute();
}
```

The problem is that the else statement is associated only with the last if statement, and the previous 5 if statements work independently.

Please note that I cannot use else-ifs, since all the fields should be validated - for example even if `s3` is invalid, `s6` must still be validated. Therefore, all the if statements must be evaluated, regardless of how many are evaluated to true.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `String` has a method `isEmtpy()` that's a more natural choice for your first if

Comment: What type are `e2`, `e3`, etc.? Do they have a method that can be used to check if an error has been set?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom e1,e2 are of Type EditTexts for Android platform. They have the setError method for throwing errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way for multiple if statements to be associated with the same else statement is by using `if-else-if...else`, which is not what you need, since you want all the if statements to be evaluated, and `if-else-if...else` will evaluate the if statements only until one is evaluated to true.

Instead, you can use a flag (boolean variable) that marks the input as invalid and use it instead of the else statement to determine if the input is valid.

```
boolean valid = true;

if(s1.equals("") || s2.equals("") || s3.equals("") || s4.equals("") || s5.equals("") || s6.equals("")) {     
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter all Details first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
    valid = false;
}   
if(!s5.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+")) {    
    e5.setError("Username cannot contain special characters");  
    valid = false;
} 
if(s5.length()<6) {
    e5.setError("Username must be a minimum of 6 characters.");
    valid = false;
} 
if(!(s3.contains("@")&& s3.contains("."))) {
    e3.setError("Enter a valid Email Id");    
    valid = false;
}   
if(!s6.equals(s7)) {
    e7.setError("Passwords dont match");
    valid = false;
} 
if(s2.length()!=10) {     
    e2.setError("Please enter a valid 10 digit number");
    valid = false;
} 
if (valid) {
    Validate v2=new Validate();
    v2.store_values(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s8);
    v2.execute();
}
```

Comment: Should be `else {valid=false;}` after each if.

Comment: @Pétur The conditions are true when some input is invalid, so `valid=false;` should not be in an else statement.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. But i was wondering if there was any such construct that can achieve this without using the boolean variable.

Comment: @SouravKanta There isn't. The only way for multiple if statements to be associated with the same else statement is by using `if-else-if..-else`, which is not what you need, since you want all the if statements to be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Set a boolean flag in all of your `if` statements. If an error occured, set it to `true`.

Then, you replace the `else` segment with another `if` statement which executes only if the boolean flag you declared is false.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a generic datatype (`String`) to store data who's values are bound by some requirements. It decreases the maintainability of your code.

A better approach would be to create datatypes which store the data. That datatype would then have additional validation logic which you could use, such as by having logic in place to reject setting the value of that datatype to something which violate your specifications.
An exmaple of such a datatype would be `Password`. `Password password = new Password("abcd");` could then throw an exception given that your specifications state that a password must be of length 5 or more characters. Futher more, you could ensure that the password only exists in memory as plain text for a very short duration, by having the constructor hash it immediately after it has been validated.

If you are using Java EE, see [javax.validation.Validator](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Validator.html) for a yet another approach.